# mysql limit keyword with maximum value

Tags: mysql, max, conditional-statements, limit

I have a paging system and I use a limit in my SQL query to retrieve needed datas for each page, let's say such as :

```
SELECT foo
FROM table
LIMIT :start, 10
```

The **:start** value is then dynamic to allow page navigation.
Now if this value is bigger than the total number of rows, the query will obviously return an empty result.

What I would like to do is to fix a kind of boundary to the **:start** parameter so it will never overstep the total number of rows and at worst return the last ten entries for example.
A kind of

```
SELECT foo
FROM table
LIMIT (
   CASE WHEN :start > (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM table
   ) THEN :limit_value
   ELSE
      :start
   END
), 10
```

Comment: Why? You're going to waste so much time and deteriorate performance only to cover a case that's rare and which, even if it happens, works as expected. Do you really think it's worth your time?

Comment: since you are willing to have two queries (the subquery you show), before getting `:start`, get the `:cnt = COUNT(*)` and set `:start = min(:start, :cnt-10):

Comment: **@Mjh** In fact it's not only for the case where the user do it deliberately. As it's an application, the user can apply actions on the rows *(such as a deletion)* so if the last page is shown and the user delete all rows, the application has to display the previous page. I just then would like to manage the displaying directly in the query instead of doing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dynamically calculating `:start` and are willing to have a subquery, do a pre-query with the number of records into `:cnt` and change

```
:start = max(0,min(:start, :cnt-10))
```

Comment: This is what I was already doing but I just wanted to know if there's a way to have a conditional **limit** in my query.

Comment: Ah, sadly not on MySQL :-(